# Where does React Native store the generated javascript bundle?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I just added a lib to remove `console.log` in my React Native (JavaScript) code.

I wanted to check if the generated bundle does not contain `console.log` as expected.

Where can I find that bundle?

My app.aab is here
`./android/app/build/outputs/bundle/release/app.aab`

And when I unzip it (yes, it's a zip file), I don't see `.js` file there

Comment: How did you unzip the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case, i just unzip my aab and find that my JS code was minified in : app/base/assets/index.android.bundle

Comment: Cool, that's what I was looking for :D, Thank you

Comment: Is this safe ? Is it possible to just copy an app by reversing that code (in index.android.bundle) to a react native project ?